# Uploading different file on different column of database table

Tags: php, mysql

I have employee form that I use to store employee full information including cv, contract papers, and other documents.

How can I upload these different files for one employee using php And mysqli?

Here what the table should look like:

```
Id  name  email  resume(file)   contract(file)   edu_docs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would highly discourge you from saving files in a database like that.**

Here are the steps that I have used before:

1. I would create a folder on the server for each user.
2. Save the filename and extension in a table.
3. Save the file to the server.
4. If I wanted to grab a file I would go to the right directory and file name.

**Examples:**

Resume = {userFiles/userID/filename}

Contract for Billy = {userFiles/{Billy'sID}/{filename}

Comment: Its the same what am trying to do but in time of fetching the files how i know if it is the resume,the contract paper or other docs

Comment: @henockwakshuma when you upload the resume or contract you add that file name in the database. Such as if someone uploaded resume.pdf in the resume form then in the table it will have:
 0, Billy, email@email.com, resume.pdf, null, null.

Comment: You could add two distinctive input fields to your upload form - one for the resume and one for contract: `<input name="resume" type="file">` and `<input name="contract" type="file">`